# jQuery ошибка "(types || "").split is not a function"

Tags: jquery, javascript

Работаю Друпалом, и обновил jQuery c 1.4 -> 1.5
И в консоли фаербага стало появляться ошибка

```
(types || "").split is not a function
```

посмотрел в самой библиотеке, вот здесь идет условие :

```
if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
fn = data;
data = undefined;
}
types = (types || "").split(" ");
while ( (type = types[ i++ ]) != null ) {
```

Помогите избавиться от этой ошибки, то есть как то можно заменить `split`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это может происходить из-за того, что в `types` может находится пустой массив или объект, который при

```
types || ""
```

вернёт `true` т.е. первый операнд, у которого естественно метода `split` нет

в первую очередь вам надо удостоверится где в вашем коде это может произойти, или же изменить код jQuery на проверку того, что  `types` - это строка:

```
types = (Object.prototype.toString.call(types) == '[object String]' 
        && types.split(' ') 
        || ['']);
```

или обычным ифом

Comment: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js

тоже пишет "split isnot a function..."

Comment: зачем ссылка на jQuery? ошибка где-то в вашем или друпаловском коде, который передаёт в качестве аргумента функции что-то не то, что нужно, как избежать я показал